# Compiling PHP + Libpuzzle to Windows

Tags: windows, compilation, mingw

I got the libpuzzle source here: http://www.pureftpd.org/project/libpuzzle/download.

I read I need MinGW to compile any C programs on windows, so I got that alot with C, C++ and mins options. Using mins I was followed: http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_MinGW

I downloaded the .tar.gz and unpacked it, executed the ./configure command and got:

`libgd2 development files are not found`

Makes sense given in the readme:

```
In order to load images, the library relies on the GD2 library.
You need to install gdlib2 and its development headers before compiling
libpuzzle.
The GD2 library is available as a pre-built package for most operating systems.
Debian and Ubuntu users should install the "libgd2-dev" or the "libgd2-xpm-dev"
package.
Gentoo users should install "media-libs/gd".
OpenBSD, NetBSD and DragonflyBSD users should install the "gd" package.
MacPorts users should install the "gd2" package.
X11 support is not required for the Puzzle library.

Once GD2 has been installed, configure the Puzzle library as usual:
```

My problem at this time is finding a libgd2-dev or like file to compile. I found this: http://mldonkey.sourceforge.net/Windows and downloaded http://www.boutell.com/gd/http/gd-2.0.33.tar.gz and it installed fine. Running `gdlib-config` outputs typical man. However, libpuzzle still says I need the "libgd2 development files", so I assume the gd I downloaded was "libgd" but just "gd" or the file I had didn't have development files. Where can I found what I need?

Here is mingw output:

```
Brian@2500K ~/libpuzzle-0.11
$ gdlib-config
Print information on GD library's version, configuration, and use.
Usage: gdlib-config [options]
Options:
        --libdir          # directory where GD library is installed
        --includedir      # directory where GD library headers are installed
        --version         # complete GD library version string
        --majorversion    # GD library major version number
        --minorversion    # GD library minor version number
        --revision        # GD library revision version number
        --ldflags         # options required for linking against GD library
        --libs            # libs required for linking against GD library
        --cflags          # options required for compiling GD library apps
        --includes        # same as --cflags
        --features        # lists optional features compiled into gd, separated
                          # by spaces. Currently (as of 2.0.26) the optional
                          # features are GD_PNG, GD_JPEG, GD_XPM, and
                          # GD_FREETYPE. When these features are reported by
                          # --features, it is safe to include calls to the
                          # related functions in your code.
        --all             # print a summary of all GD library configure options

Brian@2500K ~/libpuzzle-0.11
$ gdlib-config --includedir
/usr/local/include

Brian@2500K ~/libpuzzle-0.11
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -p
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for gdlib-config... /usr/local/bin/gdlib-config
checking for gdImageCreateFromGd2 in -lgd... no
configure: error: libgd2 development files not found
```

Edit: Started a bounty. I am looking for either compile the libpuzzle for me so it works on WAMP (skipping the complicated middle stuff). Or help on getting each requirement needed so that I can compile it. My end goal is having libpuzzle run on wamp

Edit 2: Just an update, it seems libgd2 has problems with mingw. Even if I was to get libgd2 to finally work then I still need phpize for mingw as well, which also doesn't work for mingw. It seems it's not possible to use libpuzzle for windows

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the program is just not finding the headers for libgd. If you look at that tarbar, it's a source tarball that includes the headers. When you compiled and installed it, it installed the library and the headers somewhere. You need to figure out where.

Run ./configure --help

There should be an option like --with-gd=, that option lets you tell it the path where libgd is installed. Specify the path where it is installed, and it should work.

Comment: There isn't an option like that but the configure script does detect gdlib-config which does tell it where everything is installed. I don't think this is the issue. See my updated reply

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error when compiled GD2 myself.

Using old precompiled version from GnuWin32 solved the problem:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/gd/2.0.33-1/